# Query related to wrapfig latex

Tags: latex

i am using wrapfig command in latex to wrap text around figures, but it make really bad view, when i insert 3 images consecutively. Images inserted with 'r' option appears at left side of the page. Log states that 'floating environments overlaped' 
Can anybody help me in this regard.

Comment: If you would make a [mre] that replicates your problems, we could try to help you.

Comment: \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\graphicspath{ {./} }




\begin{document}
 
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word 
\par
\indent
\needspace{8\baselineskip}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0c

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the [mre].